# uWSGI repeated execution of long running Flask app.route() function

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I'm currently running uWSGI with a Flask web app, via the command line. The command used is:

```
uwsgi --http :80 --file /scripts/flaskWebApp/app.py --callable app --processes 4 --threads 2 -b 25000 -M
```

A function tied to a Flask `@app.route()`, appears to be executing twice.  Keep in mind this is a longer running task >60 seconds. I've verified this via adding a print statement to the function. uWSGI will log it as the following:

```
10.10.10.36 [pid: 6490|app: 0|req: 3/9] 10.10.10.77 () {38 vars in 659 bytes} [Thu Mar 28 17:20:42 2013] GET /versions/1.3.0/availableQualifiers/a/incrementals/ => generated 15 bytes in 1161 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 79 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
Deploying system
17:20:46      03-28-2013
Deploying system
17:21:46      03-28-2013
```

I'm assuming this is caused by some sort of request time out. I've been trying to set timeouts on workers and harakiri (none of which helped). Is there a timeout that I'm missing?

I'm using jQuery's  ajax call `$.post()` (synchronously), to fire off the REST call. I doubt this is the issue though, seeing as it didn't happen with Flask's built-in simple web server.

Comment: If your request is running that long (60 seconds), you should really think about using task queue (like [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/)), otherwise your app won't be usable for more than a handful of users at the same time.